# NullPointerException in animation android

Tags: java, android

I got a strange (for me) `NullPointerException` error with my code, it happens only on real devices (two phone, and one tablet), but on `emulators`, it's works just fine!!

Here's the code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

    flyIn()

}
private void flyIn() {
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.logo_animation);     //<-- this line here 
    logo.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

`logo_animation` looks like :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXScale="0.1"
        android:fromYScale="0.1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromDegrees="-270"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

Stack trace :

```
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983): Process: example.animation, PID: 20983
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.animation/example.animation.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at example.animation.Splash.flyIn(Splash.java:67)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at example.animation.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:47)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5484)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
06-21 23:46:07.844: E/AndroidRuntime(20983):    ... 11 more
```

`(Splash.java:67)` which is this line:

```java
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.logo_animation);
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Comment: Based on the information you've given `R` would have to be null on the line you list. Maybe make sure it's initialized?

Comment: @lucasvw In Android the `R` class is autogenerated and it's always initialized.

Answer (score 1):

@Sarah,

Based on [Android's Drawable Animation Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html), it appears you cannot put the startAnimation() call in onCreate(). The guide discusses AnimationDrawable objects, but says

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the
>   AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of
>   your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached
>   to the window.

I suspect a similar thing is happening in your code. If you reference that guide, it talks about another way to start the animation that shouldn't have this problem.

As to why is works in an emulator; I'm at a loss. Emulators can be strange.

Comment: so, how i can call properly it outside onCreate()?

Comment: Try doing it when `onStart()` is called

Comment: The guide says to put the call to start() inside of onWindowFocusChanged(). Does this work for your case?